# How to use android handler in a loop

Tags: android, loops, android-handler

I am building my first android application and I am trying to make a memory game. Anyhow, I need to make an array of buttons change color for 1 second and then return to its original color in order, for example: button1 changes to yellow, stays like that for 1 second then returns to gray, then button2 changes to yellow for 1 second then returns, and so on. I tried using the handler but it always works only after the last iteration, this is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

                    buttonList.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);


                    runnable =new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                             buttonList.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);}
```

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
**Found How to do it.** First I need to make a runnable class that takes paramaters ex MyRunnable implements Runnable (using Runnable interface), then writing a method that uses this paramater, I can't do it with the regular one because it depends on i and i changes with the iteration.

Comment: Because ten iterations finished faster than 1 second

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Runnable inside each loop because all 9 delayed posts are running the same runnable that you create on the 9th and final loop since the loop no doubt takes less than a second to complete. So try something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    buttonList.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
             buttonList.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
         }};
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still does the same. I think that I can't use i and need to use some way to pass its value to the runnable not itself but i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You're synchronously (at the same time) setting all buttons' colors to yellow, and also creating 9 asynchronous tasks (one for each button) to change color to gray after one second. It means all buttons will change colors back to gray after around 1 second, (more or less) at the same time.

Think of the handler as a queue that you add tasks to. The call `postDelayed()` is scheduling your tasks to be executed in the future, but all of them are scheduled at the same time, so all of them will be executed at the same time in the future.

I haven't run it, but I think this approach is more of what you are looking for:

```
// Those are fields
private int buttonIndex = 0;
private boolean yellow = false;
private final Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (!yellow) {
            buttonList.get(buttonIndex).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
        } else {
            buttonList.get(buttonIndex).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            if (++buttonIndex < 9) handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        yellow = !yellow;
}});

// Call this to start the sequence.
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Note that I'm using `sendEmptyMessage*()` instead of `post*()`, but either approach could be used. Additionally, handler's messages (tasks) can have input parameters, so it'd be nice to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, still it does the say unfortunately.